# MS Access: Pass Value from Form Textbox to Another Form Combo Box on a New Record?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

Okay, bare with me, this is a really hard question to describe, and I'm fairly new to VBA.

I have a 'Customer Form' with a Command Button to create a New Order in an 'Order Form'. I can get the button to Open the 'Order Form' to a New Record, but I can't get it to pass the 'CustomerID' to the 'Order Form' Combo Box 'CustomerID'. I need the 'Order Form' to auto-populate with information from the 'Customer Form'.

**Customer Form:**
[image: Customer Form]

**Order Form:**
[image: Order Form]
The Customer Combo Box shows the Customer Full Name, but is bound to the CustomerID

**Here's the VBA Code I have tried:**

```
Private Sub BtnNewOrder_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Order Form", View:=acNormal, OpenArgs:=Me.CustomerID.Value
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.CustomerID = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
End Sub
```

**I get the following error:**
[image: Error Message]

I've been browsing the web for days without any luck. I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find the right solution. Feel free to simply point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try to always be explicit about which property you mean to assign to, instead of letting VBA do the work of figuring out what the object's *default member* is and implicitly invoking it: `CustomerID.Text = "value"` is bound at compile-time and reminds the reader that `CustomerID` isn't just a numeric value as it seems, it's actually an object with properties and methods: it's a *control* object. The line `CustomerIdBox = Me.OpenArgs` does read better already, and then if it reads `CustomerIdBox.Text = Me.OpenArgs` we just can't go wrong about the intent anymore. Good naming is half the battle!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the tip! I changed the control object names and used the property method '.Text' with some progress. Now it's pulling and placing the right data, but it's trying to match the 'CustomerForm.CustomerIDBox' integer value against the visible string column in the 'OrdersForm.CustomerBox'. The bound "id" column is hidden; I need it to match on ID not name. Does that make sense?

Comment: That would be `CustomerIdBox.Value` then, no?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon when I try ".Value" or matching the CustomerForm.Full_Name.Text to the OrderForm.CustomerBox.Text (The visible column) I don't get an error, but the value of the ComboBox doesn't change. It's as if nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the forms on-load event. The on open event is too soon.

On Open event  - allows testing of controls and values - you can set cancel = true and form will not load. So, on open is for checking/testing if you want to let the form open, based on custom code that checks things. If you don't want the form to load - you can set Cancel = true.

On Load event:
Here is where your setup code, set variables, possible set controls etc. is to occur. So you can't modify controls in on-open - too soon of a event, but you CAN modify the forms controls and values in the on-load event.

Comment: I've switched to the on-load event, and I've changed the naming like @MathieuGuindon mentioned. However, I'm still running into issues.. Trying to match the numerical CustomerID from the CustomerForm to the CustomerBox on the OrderForm gives an error: "the text you entered isn't an item in the list." The ComboBox is a two column lookup (CustomerID, Full_Name) bound to the CustomerID, but CustomerID is hidden with a 0" column width. It's like Access is trying to match the CustomerIDBox data against the Full_Name list.

Comment: As a general rule, access does use the text for the combo box. So that's the setting and it will convert to the ID for you. so use MyComboBox.Text = "some text to set", or you can use the id, and use .Value  like MyComboBox.Value = 55 --- so .Value or .Text is how you choose between setting text or the id value.